# make all gives linker command fail error in caffe installation

Tags: caffe

After following all the steps in caffe installation, I find this error:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<float>::InternalThreadEntry() in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<double>::InternalThreadEntry() in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::ReadImageToDatum(std::string const&, int, int, int, bool, caffe::Datum*) in io.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

What can be done. I tried all possible cases, reinstalling and finding in githun issues.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Same problem here :(

Comment: Please answer this if you get any solutions. I will edit the question if I get any solutions. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have not installed OpenCV in your system.
If you are using the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager, try executing the following commands

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install homebrew/science/opencv
```

If the above two line of commands do perform without any error, try building Caffe again.